# Python Linked List Query

Tags: python, object, linked-list

Here is the code I am having some issues with:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class Solution(object):
    def insert(self, head, data):
        if head == None:
            head = Node(data)
        else:
            current = head
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = Node(data)
        return head

    def display(self, head):
        current = head
        while current:
            print(current.data)
            current = current.next
```

The code itself works fine but I'm having trouble understanding the insert function. Initially,

```
Head == None
```

So a new Node is made with argument data, this will be the new head from now on. So if I try to add a new Node to this list, the else is triggered and the new node:

```
current.next
```

is created. So far so good. Now if I wish to add yet another Node, the else condition will trigger again but a new current object is being created, will this not overwrite memory of the old current and thus current.next? How can the program have memory of previous Nodes??

Than you.

Comment: Note that binding objects to names is like passing *references* by value. No new object is created, just a new reference to an existing object. `current = current.next` does not *copy* `current.next`, it merely assigns the object referred to by `current.next` to now be referred to by `current`.

Comment: I had to choose one of the others answers as best answer but your comment helped me to understand the most, thanks @MisterMiyagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current is a local variable that *points* to a Node object. Overwriting current doesn't destroy the Node, it just makes current point to something else. As long as you have a reference to what current used to point to, you're fine. In this case, because you keep a hold of *head*, you're always able to work your way through the list.

Answer (score 1):

No, a new current object is not being created, but rather the variable current is being reassigned until it hits the last element in the list, and only then is a new Node object created and assigned to the end of the list.